# Windows Command Line -- Find text within line at certain position

Tags: windows, command-line

What Windows/DOS command line utility would one use to find 17 characters, starting at the 45th command line position of a daily revised text file?

Can this be done with 'TYPE'?

Sample daily text file contents:

XXXX_XXXXX.txt:XXXX (XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:(none)): 01-25-16  05:26AM            XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX.zip

Thanks.

---

I assume it could be done by a combination of SET and TYPE.

How would you define a variable as the text within a text file (which will only be one line (by using FINDSTR))?

Thanks.

Comment: My problem was resolved.   I used SET to assign a variable from the text file   [Example: SET /p variable=<X:\Text_File.txt], then SET another variable to select the date and time information from that set text format.     [Example: SET Export_date_time=%variable:~30,17%]

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer). You might want to convert your comment into an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was resolved. I used SET to assign a variable from the text file:

Example: SET /p Directory_Contents=Text_File.txt

(Actually, a '<' is also supposed to be between '=' and 'Text_File.txt, but there is a formatting issue that invalidates it.)

Here are the sample contents of the daily updated 'Text_File.txt'.  Fortunately, the position of the characters I'm need never change.

XXXX_XXXXX.txt:XXXX (XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:(none)): 01-25-16 05:26AM XXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX.zip

Then SET another variable to select the date and time information from that set text format.

Example: SET Export_date_time=%Directory_Contents:~30,17%

The character starting point and length were revised from what I thought the command line would identify as the contents.

Thanks to all from this (and other) forums for assistance in determining this solution.